# Template Engine (ejs) issues found

Tags: node.js, express

```html
                            SUBMIT EJS FILE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Your password has been changed click here for <a href="user">login</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

MY PASSWORD CLASS

class Password {

```
constructor(newPass,confirmPass) {

    this.newPass=newPass;
    this.confirmPass=confirmPass;    
}
```

}
module.exports=Password;

**MY ROUTING FILE**

```
seller.post('/change',(req,res)=>{

    console.log('kkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
    res.render('change');
    var newPass=req.body.newPass;
    console.log("New Password:::",newPass);
    var confirmPass=req.body.confirmPass;
    console.log('Confirm Password:::',confirmPass);   
    var passPanel=new password(newPass,confirmPass);
    var pr=operations.findOneAndUpdate(passPanel);

    pr.then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        res.render('change',{newPass:data.newPass, confirmPass:data.confirmPass});

    })
})


             seller.post('/submit',(req,res)=>{
            res.render('submit');
           });
      module.exports=seller;
```

MY SERVER CONFIGURATION

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use('/', require('./Routes/sellerRoutes'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT||1234, (err)=>{

    if(err) {
        console.log('An Error has occured', err);
        logger.error('Server Not Start ',err);
    }

    else {

        console.log("Server Started");
        logger.debug('Server Started');
    }
})
```

MY EJS FILE CODE

```
<body class="section">
    <h1><center>Password Change</center></h1>
    <form method="POST" action="submit">
        <% var newPass;%> <% var confirmPass; %>
        <label for="">New Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newPass" value="<%=newPass%>">

    <div class="cnfrm">
        <label for="">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPass" name="confirmPass" value="<%=confirmPass%>">
    </div>
        <button id="chngepswd" class="btn btn-success">OK</button></a>
    </form>
    <br>
</body>
```

**When I am coding in node. I made an ejs template in which I've made a form. Form is using method POST. When I am routing it with POST method it does not render the page and it says CANNOT GET.**

On the other hand, when I am using it with GET request it is absolutely working fine means it is rendering me the ejs page that I've made.

I'm not able to understand why my ejs is rendering me the page with GET request and not with POST request.

Comment: Can you share some code? Your form action is probably wrong, but without code is just a lot of guessing

Comment: @RaduDiță can u provide me your email . I'm trying to post the question but stack overflow dies not allow me because of format.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only telling you to not post a "screenshot image" of your code. Instead of taking a screenshot, copy the "text" of your code and paste it into the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm not posting any screenshot I'm copying the code but it says me to add some comments and when I'm adding comments still it shows error of adding comments.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've posted my code.

Comment: @RaduDiță I've posted my code

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` on the form is **submit**

`<form method="POST" action="submit">`

This means the browser will try to access **/submit**, but you don't seem to have a route for that.

You probably need to change the action to **/change**.

Comment: I have made a page  where I want user to setup new password and confirm password and when it presses ok button it ten routes directly to submit page. Let me update my code

Answer (score 0):

In your `seller.post` method, you are calling `res.render` 2 times. This will not work because `res.render` sends HTTP response back to the client and you can't send 2 responses to one request.

While `res.render` doesn't need to be the last statement in your method, it cannot be followed by another piece of code that generates response as one has already been sent.

You should remove the first `res.render` in your method.